# Output after select in PS script is empty

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get user certificate info from AD using this:

```
$user1 = Get-ADUser %username% -Properties “Certificates”
$user1.certificates | foreach {New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_} | fl *
```

But when I'm trying to `select` something from output, I'm getting empty data such as:

```
$user1 = Get-ADUser %username% -Properties “Certificates”
$user1.certificates | foreach {New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_} | fl * | select subject

subject                                                                                                                     
-------
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: You selecting from format objects, returned by `Format-List`, them does not have `subject` property.

Comment: `fl` = `Format-List` - don't use formatting cmdlets in the middle of a pipeline - they should always be the last thing you call

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about formatting.